# Plugin to Rerun failed tests on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, automated-tests, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Is there a plugin for Jenkins CI to rerun only the failed tests, I can do it with a rerun profile and a cucumber rake task, but is there a plugin already ?

Also aware of Naginator plugin which runs the entire build on failure

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Naginator+Plugin

but I want to run only the failed tests from the previous build

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [Flaky Test Handler Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Flaky+Test+Handler+Plugin)

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. How does this plugin perform? Any suggestions for a group about to implement it?